# What TBBs or finishing actions are responsible for putting linked components in a database?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, broker, dxa-1.6

I'm using Tridion 8.5 and DXA 1.6. I have schema A, which uses embedded schema Q, and has a component link to Schema Z.

Schema A only has one component template (which is published embedded on the page) When I preview a component made with Schema A, I see the data from the linked components (that use Schema Z). The component Template has `expandLinkDepth` set to 6, which seems to be more than enough.

Upon publishing the page, the broker database does not have data from the Schema Z components at all. The data indicates that we know how *many* component links there are. But we're not seeing any data from those components at all.

This only happens in one environment (production, of course). Our QA environment works fine. We've ruled out problems with the DXA application, or issues withing the databases themselves.

Given the fact that this is a problem in one environment, and not the other, I'm wondering if there's an issue specifically with the Default Finish Actions TBBs, or any other TBBs that we are using.

Could someone tell me what Template Building Blocks are responsible for making sure that, upon publish of a page, content of a linked component makes it into a DB?

*Edit*
Looks like my issue is related to this issue here: [DXA 1.5 intermittent issue in JSON output](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/dxa-1-5-intermittent-issue-in-json-output).

Symptoms are almost identical, including the poorly formatted JSON and presence of `renderedContent` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion of Component Links is done in DD4T TBBs (DXA 1.x) or the [DXA Model Builders](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DataModelBuilder.cs) in DXA R2.

Note that static (CM-side) expansion means that the data of the linked Component/Keyword is embedded in the data of the linking item; the linked Component/Keyword is not published as separate entity.

DXA 2.0 can also do dynamic (CD-side) expansion, but I digress.

Back to your problem: the TBB used to generate the DD4T Data Model (incl. Component link expansion) in DXA 1.5+ is called [“Generate Dynamic Page (DXA)”](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/1.6/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/DD4T/GenerateDynamicPage.cs). The point is: only since DXA 1.7 did this TBB get its own Parameter Schema and a parameter called `expandLinkDepth`; in DXA 1.6 it still used the DD4T Parameter Schema and the parameter was called `linkLevel` (IIRC).

So, I guess the difference between the two environments is the DXA version installed?

BTW: `expandLinkDepth` of 6 sounds like more than enough to me! This may result in a huge graph of Components being rendered/published!

Comment: It looks like the issue is this here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/dxa-1-5-intermittent-issue-in-json-output

it has nothing to do with `expandLinkDepth`, apparently. I reviewed the JSON from the microservices from both environments and I see the `renderedContent` attribute, as well as double-escaped JSON. It appears that it's a deserialization issue. The bigger question is why I have it in one environment and not the otther, but I suspect that perhaps a TBB was updated somewhere.